# How do I get Ironclads/Submarines lifted into an in-atmosphere wormhole that leads into another identical one?

Tags: spaceships, ships, airships, wormholes, rogue-planets

I am working on some lore for an overhaul mod, but I want to try to stay away from handwavium as much as I can, at first.

There's two terran planets connected by many stable wormholes, the most ruckus they can cause are weak hurricane winds when numerous foreign objects enter them at once. Most are located in the Troposphere, 10-30 miles in the air, the rest drifting between the stratosphere and mesosphere of both planets. Lastly, most of these wormholes are located closer to the poles and over deep water.

Long ago they used to be navigated by advanced starships, but now civilization on both worlds is equivalent from the Renaissance to the Industrial age, and the most industrialized nations produce armored warships that are somehow guided into the wormholes where when it takes approximately 7 days to end the journey at the other mouth.

I just can't think of anything feasible and somewhat easily producible to do so. Can airships airlift Ironclads on one planet, and the Ironclads have rudimentary chemical rockets that are somewhat realistic, that propel them safely onto water on other end? Or instead of Ironclads, they're iron-barges that are massive troop transports?

Or is the prerequisite WW2-era technology, with frigates and destroyers solely designed for the launch and landing between wormholes with limited sea-faring ability?

Comment: To lift a ship out of water one needs excessive care and a very very careful arrangement of supports. Ships are fragile things, they cannot sustain their own weight if lifted carelessly. It is much simpler to lift the ship *with the surrounding water*. That's what [boat lifts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boat_lift) do. (Remember how much effort was expended to move that ship which had [managed to place itself across the Suez canal](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2021/03/what-will-it-take-to-get-a-giant-cargo-ship-unstuck-from-the-suez-canal) a few months ago.)

Comment: How do you explain moving frigates and destroyers into the wormholes? WW2 flight tech is at its peak V2 style rockets, primitive helicopters, airplanes, and blimps. For example, a B-17 heavy bomber at max altitude could only reach ~6.74 miles up. The famous jet fighter ME 262 could barely go above 7 miles with a good engine. This is much less than 10 miles to a whopping 30 miles needed to reach the wormholes, especially with only WW2 tech.

Comment: I could move water, though that sounds very hard to do, hmm.

I don't know how to explain frigates and destroyers into the wormhole, I was suggesting something. I thought something rudimentary could be done, but I guess I have to come up with some fictional engine design.

Comment: There's also a scale issue in flying ships around. The Antonov An-225, the largest cargo aircraft ever flown, has a maximum payload weight in the neighborhood of 250t. Even a primitive ironclad like *USS Monitor* will displace in the realm of 1,000t. They're too big to be flown at all, let alone 10 miles up.

Comment: Some reality: the highest flying commercial plane was the Concorde at 11 miles. The highest flying military plane (not a rocket) was the SR-71 at 17 miles. Your highest commercial jet today flies at 8.5 miles. None of that tech existed before the 1960s and none of it is practical to get an ironclad (770 ***tons***) off the ground (much less to 10-30 miles). The largest cargo plane is the Antonov AN-225... 600 tons including its own weight and fuel. You can't even use the highest mountain (Everest @ 5.5 miles) to help. This Q seems to be a slam dunk: handwaving or lower those portals... a lot.

Comment: I don't think any real airships can get up to 30 miles into the atmosphere.

Comment: @NomadMaker, in the known history of humanity, only rockets have reached 30 miles into the atmosphere. See "[Rockets - What's the largest single object payload ever lifted into space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/13657/whats-the-largest-single-object-payload-ever-lifted-into-space)" on our sister site, [space.se] and remember an ironclad weighed about 770 tons.

Comment: There are unmanned atmospheric baloons that went up this far. "During 2002 an ultra-thin-film balloon named BU60-1 made of polyethylene film 3.4 µm thick with a volume of 60,000 m³ was launched from Sanriku Balloon Center at Ofunato City, Iwate in Japan at 6:35 on May 23, 2002. The balloon ascended at a speed of 260 m per minute and reached the altitude of 53.0 km (173,900 ft)". 53km=33 miles. I am not convinced about using baloons to lift ships though. The required volume to lift the ship is and added issue to the ship's own limited integrity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a really interesting problem:

"How do I realistically get a submarine/surface ship up to around 10 miles safely through a wormhole, and then proceed to get it down safely onto the surface of the ocean?"

Even if you do figure out a way to lift up an ironclad 10 miles up, you still have to safely and slowly drop them down 10 miles on the other side; which would probably require a team to construct the necessary infrastructure beforehand; else you risk your vehicle nose-diving head first into the ocean from 10 miles up when it passes through the wormhole. Since you're already sending teams out to do construction work; why not just send a few hundred workers and engineers with the necessary materials through a wormhole; and build an ocean-dock of sorts to build the iron clads and submarines? if you worry about enemy vessels approaching the construction site; you can always have air vehicles scout and secure the area on the other side first.

So, to sum up my answer; you have two options:

1. Lower the wormholes down to only a couple dozen feet above the ocean, so that we can feasibly use a Boat-lift (as mentioned in the comments) to transport whole submarines/ships
2. use Forward operating bases/factories to construct submarines/surface warships*

(*another thing I would like to add, is that you can also do what some construction companies do called "[Modular Construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_building)"; and haul/fly over pre-built pieces of a submarine/ship through the wormhole (which is more realistic), and then weld them together on the other side (Modular Shipbuilding?).)

Comment: Thank you for your answer really appreciate it. I think your right about lowering the wormholes. I was thinking about going down the anti-gravity route as well, but I will lower the wormholes.